# ajax API data outputs in console but won't attach to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below function is running, and outputting my data into the console using `console.log(data);` however anytime I try to pass it to output as HTML, I get 'data' is not defined?

```
   .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("HTTP Request Succeeded: " + jqXHR.status);
        console.log(data); // Works.
        // $('.content').html(data); // Doesn't. Although the data param is clearly defined    
    })
```

Additionally, right inline of the ajax request I have tried adding the function - but still won't apply.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "https://yesitworks.com/WorkingAPIkey",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            "countries": "US",
        },
        headers: {
            "X-API-Key": "WorkingAPIkey",
        },
        success: function(data){ // Fully ignored. Then run it in console and data undefined. But it's defined as param.
            $('.content').html(data);       
        }       
    })
```

I have also tried using append prepend etc etc.

Using suggested `.text` outputs:

**[object Object]** as opposed to the data parsed, which is many objects.

Comment: What is the exact error or result you get? Is an error thrown or does the element appear empty on the page?

Comment: Can you show code for content class

Comment: Element is empty on the page. I only get data undefined when I rerun the attempted code in console alone.

Comment: $('.content').text(data); may help

Comment: <div class="content"></div>

Comment: @nikunjMnage that makes no sense regarding OP error

Comment: Have you tried inserting other static content into the element? Like `$('.content').text('some stuff here')`

Comment: There is no way `data` is not defined in success handler. There is something you aren't showing us. Sounds like you are trying to access it outside the success callback

Comment: So using .text output '[object Object]' but not the actual data.

Comment: console.log(data); // Works. - Is the output html string?

Comment: @cdev.co can you copy what you see in console and paste it here .. ? whole object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) states it accepts either an HTML string or a function that returns an HTML string. You can't directly display an object on the page. If you just want to dump the object, you need to stringify it:

```
$('.content').html(JSON.stringify(data));
```

A value or identifier being `undefined` has a very specific meaning in JavaScript. If the identifier `data` was undefined, you'd get an error thrown. If the identifier has no assigned value (like declaring `const data;`), it literally has the value of `undefined`. In your case an object cannot be converted directly to HTML, and therefore the element is empty.

Comment: I believe this is it as well - am trying it now.